# brew link git Error: git has multiple installed versions

Tags: git, homebrew

I have unlinked kegs as follows:

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
    git
```

but trying to link them gives:

```
$ brew link git
Error: git has multiple installed versions
$ git --version
git version 2.3.2 (Apple Git-55)
```

Should I abandon one of my git kegs? Or ignore the warning?

Comment: Have you tried running `brew cleanup`?

Comment: That's definitely cleaned things up - logs, caches, etc - but not fixed the `git` problem.

Comment: Try `brew link git` again.

Comment: Same - $ brew link git
Error: git has multiple installed versions

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have installed `git` with Homebrew and through a `.dmg` downloaded from the `git` website. You can resolve the Homebrew **warning** with

```
$ brew remove git
```

and continue to use the current version of `git` that you are using. Alternatively you could uninstall the downloaded `git` version and link the Homebrew `git` version with

```
$ brew link git
```

you may also be able to force Homebrew to overwrite your downloaded `git` version, depending on permissions, with

```
$ brew link --overwrite git
```

and then continue to use Homebrew's version of `git`.

---

Just to note, the issue you have highlighted in your question is a **warning** and **not** an error. Ignoring it is a perfectly valid course of action in this situation too.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all above without succeed, the only solution was to delete the folder for that formula manually

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/git
```

Comment: I don't believe you need to do that manually. `brew` provides clean ways to uninstall something, with explicit error messages. Likely, doing `brew remove --force --ignore-dependencies git` should have succeed in the same way.